# Perpendicular velocities (special relativity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Imagine that you are traveling in a spaceship that passes by Earth at a velocity of $v$ (Lorentz factor = $\gamma$), and you fire an escape pod from your spaceship pointed straight up (in the $y$ or $z$ direction, perpendicular to the spaceship’s direction of travel). If the escape pod has a perpendicular speed of $u_y'$ with respect to your ship, what is the perpendicular speed of the escape pod $u_y$ from the perspective of a person on Earth?

**My attempt:**

I prefer not to use the formula, but rather reason my way through.

Consider a time interval of $\Delta t$ on Earth. This corresponds to a time interval of $\Delta t/\gamma$ on the spaceship, due to time dilation, wherein the escape pod travels a distance of $u_y'\Delta t/\gamma$ upwards. So, the perpendicular speed with respect to the Earth $u_y=\displaystyle\frac{u_y'\Delta t/\gamma}{\Delta t}=u_y'/\gamma$.

Is my reasoning fine?

Comment: Does your reasoning give the same result as the formula that you prefer not to use?

Comment: @G. Smith Yes, I think so.